# Test Connection from nodejs application to Oracle DB

Tags: node.js, oracle, electron, node-oracledb

I have developed a desktop application with electron nodejs.I have a requirement to do Test connection to Oracle Database. I have all the details of database source information in my application.How can I do test connection from my application.

have attached screenshot below of the application
[image]

Comment: Any answers please

Comment: "_I have a requirement to do Test connection to Oracle Database_" do you already have a "normal" connection to an Oracle db from your application? Is your requirement to just add the "test connection" feature?

Answer (score 1):

`hostname` should be *just* the hostname, not `hostname:port/service_name`. i.e. "localhost" if the database is on the same server as the application, or the actual remote hostname or IP address if it is running somewhere else.